# How do you count occurrences of each element in an array?

Tags: java

Write a java program or function to count the occurrences of each element in an array. For example, if `{12, 9, 12, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11}` is the input array, then the count of occurrences of each element is `{12:2, 9:3, 10:2, 11:1}`.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with Java Collections?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Map`:

```java
public static Map<String, Integer> histogram(String[] arr) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(String item : arr)
        map.put(item, map.getOrDefault(item, 0) + 1);

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this using `LinkedHashMap` to keep insertion order:

1. Using Java Stream

- `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.counting()`:

```java
static Map<Integer, Long> frequencyCounting(int ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     i -> i, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()
                 ));
}
```

- `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.summingInt`:

```java
static Map<Integer, Integer> frequencySumming(int ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                     i -> i, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1)
                 ));
}
```

- `Collectors.toMap`

```java
static Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMap(int ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                     x -> x, x -> 1, Integer::sum, LinkedHashMap::new
                 ));
}
```

2. `for` loop and `Map::merge` function

```java
static Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMapMerge(int ... arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i : arr) {
        map.merge(i, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return map;
}
```

- `Map::compute`

```java
static Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMapCompute(int ... arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i : arr) {
        map.compute(i, (k, prev) -> null == prev ? 1 : prev + 1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

- `Map.put + computeIfAbsent`

```java
static Map<Integer, Integer> frequencyMapCompute(int ... arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i : arr) {
        map.put(i, map.computeIfAbsent(i, v -> 0) + 1);
    }
    return map;
}
```